# DocuSign: Unable to upload pdf Document via API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create a new envelope via api, but getting the following error message:

```
<errorDetails xmlns=""http://www.docusign.com/restapi"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
  <errorCode>UNABLE_TO_LOAD_DOCUMENT</errorCode>
  <message>Unable to load the document. Unable to load Document(XXXXX.pdf). 
  Error: Value must be non negative. & vbLf & "Parameter name: Height</message>
</errorDetails>
```

Could you help with the problem? Not sure why it's happening.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide the file, because it contains sensitive information

Comment: I tried to upload the pdf document using UI and everything worked fine, but uploading is not working for api

Comment: Does this fail with every PDF? Can you provide an API log with the document base64 redacted?

Comment: is it a flattened PDF or any specific type of PDF?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please up vote all useful answers, including answers to questions by others. Please check (accept) the best answer to your own questions.

Comment: @AmitKBist Not sure how to check the type of PDF. I just saw that it was created in Bluebeam Revu application. It's some kind of architecture design diagram

Comment: Try uploading PDF directly using DocuSign WebApp - Send an Envelope and see if you get any error on the upload.

Comment: If its working with DocuSign WebApp, then capture the API logs by following this [link](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging). It will give you exact API which DS WebApp is firing and try to use same in your API code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the PDF worked when you uploaded it to DocuSign via the DocuSign web tool, the problem lies in how you uploaded it via the API.

When uploading via the API:

1. Set the `fileExtension` attribute to "pdf" or whatever the source format is. Eg "html", "docx", etc.
2. Set the `documentBase64` attribute to the [BASE64 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) value of your source document.

I suggest you examine the code example for your preferred language to see how this is done:

[C#](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core),
[PHP](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant),
[Java](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant), 
[Node.js](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant), 
[Python](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant), 
[Ruby](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-ruby-auth-code-grant), 
[Curl (direct API)](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-curl)

Look at how scenario 1 or 2 reads and then uploads the source document to DocuSign.

If your document is larger than 15MBytes or so, you may want to upload to DocuSign using a binary transfer technique. To do so, see the examples' scenario number 10.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using existing legacy functionality which sends requests using multipart form requests. As it was described here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/requests-and-responses

Comment: The functionality is working fine for several years and we only have an issue with a specific file

Comment: Could you help with multipart upload? I can share the file caused error with you if you want

Comment: See the examples' scenario 10 for how to use multipart upload. Or open a new question and share your uploading code. (Not the PDF file or other private information.) Also try to narrow down the failure scenario. Is it the size of the PDF, some other issue? If the PDF works via the DocuSign web tool then it should work via the API.

Comment: I used the source code from the scenario 10 to send the file as multipart/form-data and got the same error:
{"errorCode": "UNABLE_TO_LOAD_DOCUMENT",  "message": "Unable to load the document. Unable to load Document(1;xxx.pdf). Error: Value must be non negative.\r\nParameter name: Height" }

So, the issue is definitely related with api issue. I can provide the file to support team, so you can reproduce the problem on your end.

Comment: Please let me know how can I contact you directly?

Comment: You can contact DocuSign support via your DocuSign technical/business contacts or via https://support.docusign.com/contactSupport

Comment: I had a call with the support team and they asked me to submit my question to stackoverflow.